# Проблемы отображения вкладки с репутацией в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Заходим в профиль на [страницу репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=post), видим примерно следующее:

[image: страница профиля с репутацией]

Есть следующие проблемы:

1. Заголовок внутренней вкладки — «уважение», заголовок в контенте — «репутация». Непоследовательно. С своё время на meta.ХК был [выбран перевод «репутация»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3424/) и «баллы репутации».
2. Заголовок наподобие «500 репутация» напоминает старое доброе время плохо переведённых игр под ДОС. Гораздо лучше смотрелось бы «500 баллов репутации». Если для этого нужно несколько форм (500 баллов, 501 балл и т. д.), а они не предусмотрены, надо сообщить баг на meta.SO.
3. Текст наподобие «3 — общее количество событий» слишком длинный, звучит слишком официально, и кроме того выглядит в текущей вёрстке некрасиво. Давайте заменим на «3 события», а? Если у кого-то есть идея по поводу более русского оборота, улучшения приветствуются.

Comment: Надо пройтись по **всем строкам** с текстом "общее количество" и последовательно их уничтожить. Раньше весь профиль был усеян этим кошмаром. теперь хоть он сносно вынлядит.

Comment: Надо просто поднарпячься и сделать еще одну итерацию в локализации. Заревьювить все предложенные строки в transifex и выгрузить их еще раз.

Comment: @Athari последовательно не стоит. По большей части эта формулировка фигурирует в переводах обоснованно.

Comment: @andreycha Покажите мне хоть одно обоснованное место в интерфейсе.

Comment: Везде, где в оригинале стоит формулировка "total count"/"total amount".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Изменил на "репутация".
2. Не нашел этой строчки (поиск в Транзифексе оставляет желать лучшего).
3. Оставил комменты с флажками с формулировкой "Х события(-ий)".