# Перевод сообщения о неправильном содержании комментария

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Думаю, стоит перевести вторую строку

> "Please see: Why can't I post LMGTFY links?".

Кроме того, предлагаю поставить в этом тексте ссылку, например, сюда: [Как бороться с некачественными вопросами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421/196573), ибо далеко не каждый начнёт гуглить "Мету" в поисках причины, почему он не должен так делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** даже не спрашивайте, как я узнал о существовании этого сообщения (:

Comment: Ближайший аналог у нас это ["Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: А как воспроизвести?

Comment: @Qwertiy Добавить в комментарий к вопросу на SO ссылку http://lmgtfy.com/ - правда, на Мете нет такой проверки, видимо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Добавил перевод.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]